# script not defined issue

Tags: javascript, asp.net, onclick

I have a simple aspx page that has a two radio buttons and a few text boxes. Both radio buttons have the same GroupName so when you check one the other is unchecked.  I would like to be able to disable the text boxes under the radio buttons depending on which radio is clicked.  I wrote a method to do that however I am getting an unhandled exception stating 'UseDates_Onclick' is undefined or 'UseWithinThePast_OnClick' is undefined depening on which radio button I check. Any ideas where I am going wrong?

**View**

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" Checked="True" GroupName="DateTimeQuery" 
OnClick="UseDates_OnClick"/>
<asp:TextBox ID="startdatetext" runat="server" MaxLength="10"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="enddatetext" Enabled="true" runat="server" MaxLength="10"></asp:TextBox>



<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton2" runat="server" GroupName="DateTimeQuery" OnClick="UseWithinThePast_OnClick"/>
<asp:TextBox ID="withinthepast" runat="server" Text="1"></asp:TextBox>
```

**Methods**

```
protected void UseDates_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            withinthepast.Enabled = false;
        }
 protected void UseWithinThePast_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            startdatetext.Enabled = false;
            enddatetext.Enabled = false;
        }
```

Comment: What does "I am getting undefined" mean?

Comment: sorry I was just editing that.  I get an unhandled exception saying 'UseWithinThePast_OnClick' is undefined and same goes for 'UseDates_OnClick' depending on which radio button I select

Comment: That sounds like a JavaScript error, not a C# error.  Which would mean that there's something *very wrong* with your setup here, because the browser shouldn't be trying to call those functions in JavaScript.

Comment: Your OnClick method references need to be for JavaScript methods not C# methods... you simply need to rewrite your C# methods as JavaScript and place them within the <script> tag for page

Comment: Why don't you use RadioButtonList with OnSelectedIndexChanged event: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.onselectedindexchanged(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks for your input I will see what I can come up with using OnSelectedIndexChanged event